# Open PrimeFaces dialog wihout commandButton

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have this link defined in my app:

```
<a href="${request.contextPath}/pages/help/applicationHelpVersion.jsf" title="#{msg['menu.version']}" onclick="window.open(this.href, 'applicationHelpVersion','left=20,top=20,width=400,height=300,toolbar=0,resizable=1'); return false;">#{msg['menu.version']}</a>
```

This solution opens new browser window with current app version number.

I would like to redefine it so that **new dialog window** opens.

I use primefaces and there is Modal Dialog I would like to use but it is combined with commandButton in all examples.

Here is applicationHelpVersion.xhtml:

```
<ui:composition
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
        xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
        xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
        xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" xmlns:hr="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"

        template="/layout/helpLayout.xhtml">


    <ui:define name="insert-application-content">
        <div style="text-align:center">
            <h1><h:outputText value="version: "/><span class="applicationVersionContent">${versionContext.productVersion}</span></h1>
            <!--<h1><h:outputText value="stage: "/><span class="applicationVersionContent">${versionContext.productNameExtension}</span></h1>-->
        </div>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

Can you please help me how to open new Modal Dialog with the app version? I tried something like this:

```
<a href="${request.contextPath}/pages/help/applicationHelpVersion.jsf" title="#{msg['menu.version']}" onclick="PF('dlg1').show();">return false;">#{msg['menu.version']}</a>

<p:dialog header="Modal Dialog" widgetVar="dlg2" modal="true" height="100">
    <h:outputText value="here will be version of app..."/>
</p:dialog>
```

I don't really know what to set as a href parameter here or if it can be done this way. At this state the app version is shown in new .jsf page but I need the dialog windows. Can you please help me? Thank you.

Comment: You can use `<p:dialog visible="true" .....>`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `href` attribute on the link because you aren't actually linking to a different page. Use the onclick of the link to open the dialog using Primefaces' javascript library like this:

```
<a onclick="PF('versionDialog').show();">My link text</a>
<p:dialog widgetVar="versionDialog">
    <h:outputText value="#{elToGetVersionInfo}" />
</p:dialog>
```

With this example, your link text will not be styled like a hyperlink because there is no `href` attribute. If you want the text to be styled like a link, use `href="#"` on the anchor tag.

Your example at the bottom of your question was close but your onclick is trying to use a `widgetVar` of `dlg1` instead of `dlg2` which is what the dialog has.